# Why doesn't jquery call the success handler in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post

I have this code:

```
$.post( "/ankauf/", {
        "kunden_id" : 1,
        "products" : products,
        "full_price" : parseInt($('#totalPrice').text()),
        "_token" : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    function( data ) {            
        toastr.success("Ankauf abgeschlossen", "OK!");
    }
);
```

Which fires an post request to my Server like I do it often in my Application.

Chrome shows this request like this:

```
Request Method:POST  
Status Code:200 OK  
Remote Address:192.168.178.80:1414
```

And the response is shown like this:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache  
Connection:close  
Content-Type:application/json

Response content:  
array(7) {  
  ["product_id"]=>  
  string(1) "5"  
  ["paidprice"]=>  
  string(2) "85"  
  ["condition"]=>  
  string(8) "Sehr Gut"  
  ["ovp1"]=>  
  string(1) "0"  
  ["ovp2"]=>  
  string(1) "0"  
  ["ovp3"]=>  
  string(1) "0"  
  ["ovp4"]=>  
  string(1) "0"  
}  
{"full_price":"85","updated_at":"2016-06-27 14:01:55","created_at":"2016-06-27 14:01:55","id":73,"created_by_id":1,"customer_id":1}
```

So the Servers response looks like a valid JSON response and the http-code is 200 any Ideas why the success handler does not fire?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is valid JSON:

> ```
> {"full_price":"85","updated_at":"2016-06-27 14:01:55","created_at":"2016-06-27 14:01:55","id":73,"created_by_id":1,"customer_id":1}
> ```

But this is not:

> ```
> array(7) {
> ["product_id"]=>
> string(1) "5"
> ["paidprice"]=>
> string(2) "85"
> ["condition"]=>
> string(8) "Sehr Gut"
> ["ovp1"]=>
> string(1) "0"
> ["ovp2"]=>
> string(1) "0"
> ["ovp3"]=>
> string(1) "0"
> ["ovp4"]=>
> string(1) "0"
> }
> {"full_price":"85","updated_at":"2016-06-27 14:01:55","created_at":"2016-06-27
> 14:01:55","id":73,"created_by_id":1,"customer_id":1}
> ```

It looks like the server is using PHP and there is a `print_r` before the statement that prints the JSON.

Comment: There was a var_dump in the php-code. I thought this was some stuff formatted by the chrome-developer-tools. Thanks for your help. Will accept in 8 minutes.